# How do/did chemists observer/infer the structure of organic molecules and reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

As I understand organic chemistry there is no simple generalization that allows us to predict reaction outcomes- rather we transform molecules using a sequence of known reactions.

This has me wondering how these known reactions came to be known. My first guess would be that the structure was empirically observed before and after the reaction.  If this is the case what instrumentation would be used to observe this?

If not, how else were these reactions determined and if they were not all developed by trial and error, what is the name of the branch of chemistry that deals with hypothesizing them?

Comment: "How do" and "How did" are two completely different, albeit both very good, questions. Voting to close as too broad. Pick one for this question, and if need be ask a new question for the other.

Comment: Spectroscopy is how they do it.

Comment: My understanding of spectroscopy is that it gave you information about composition, not structure, but I'm still a student so maybe that's not quite right.

Comment: Nope, spectroscopy can give lots of direct structural information. The first thing that comes to mind is the different 2D NMR techniques.

Comment: Because other people can describe them better, here's a list to get started, in the order I recall them: NMR, UV-vis, IR, XRC if possible, HPLC-MS, radiography, chemical testing, physical testing.

Comment: With a mix of techniques and chemistry. The question is closed but I wonder nobody mentioned chemistry at is best. Chemical structures well pre-dates spectroscopy especially the most advanced one. Fisher established the entire sugars using just chemistry and a polarimeter. Benzene was known to be a regular exagon by looking at various derivatives.  An so on. Of course nowadays is way much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Various crystallographic techniques exist, the lab technique I have used most is x-ray crystallography

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1186895/pdf/mp53000008.pdf

Currently I specialize in computational chemistry, which can estimate (with very high accuracy) the geometry of a molecule which gives the lowest energy (aka the equilibrium geoemetry) through a process called geoemetry optimization

https://www.shodor.org/chemviz/optimization/students/background.html